# Problem related to $n^{th}$-root of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $n>1$ be an integer, $k$ be an integer such that gcd(k,n)=1 and $w\neq 1$ be an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. Show that,
 $$1+w^k+w^{2k}+\ldots+w^{(n-1)k}=0$$
I tried this problem in this way let
$w=e^{\frac{2\pi ip}{n}}$, where $1\leq p\leq n-1$. If $w^{k}\not=1$ then we have done because\
$$1+w^k+w^{2k}+\ldots+w^{(n-1)k}=\frac{1-w^{nk}}{1-w^{k}}.$$  Now using the condition $gcd(n,k)$ how to show that $w^{k}\not=1.$

Comment: If $a^k-1=0, a^n-1=0$ Using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1, $$a^{(k,n)}-1=0$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right. I am deleting my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $w^k=1$ and $w^n=1$ and $\gcd(n,k)=1$ impliy that $w=1$ by *Bézout's identity*.

Indeed, if $ak+bn=1, \enspace(a,bv\in\mathbf Z)$, then
$$w=w^{ak+bn}=(w^k)^a\cdot(w^n)^b=1^a\cdot1^b=1.$$